# Вывод данных из бд по id Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3

Есть телеграмм бот для сервисного центра авто, надо при нажатии на кнопку "вывести клиентов" они выходят все, нада сделать так чтобы я через клавиатуру вбил id и открыл этого пользователя и поменял там статус(в работе, ожидает и т.д) через кнопку

```py
elif message.text == "Ремонт": 
#элементы главного меню
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard= True) 
item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Ремонт')
item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Ожидание')
markup.add(item1,item2)
script_path = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[0]).parent  # абсолютный путь до каталога, где лежит скрипт
connect = sqlite3.connect(script_path / "data.db")  # формируем абсолютный путь до файла базы
cursor = connect.cursor() 
#вывод из базы данных всех вопрос и ответов
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM client ")
id = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Name FROM client")
Имя = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Surname FROM client")
Фамилия = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Otchestvo FROM client")
Отчество = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Telephone FROM client")
Телефон = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Marka FROM client ")
Марка = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Model FROM client ")
Модель = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Problem FROM client")
Проблема = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Probeg FROM client")
Пробег = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT Status FROM client")
Статус = cursor.fetchall()
connect.close()

message_str = ""
i = 0
while i < min(len(id), len(Имя), len(Фамилия), len(Отчество),len(Телефон), len(Марка), len(Модель),len(Проблема), len(Пробег),len(Статус)):
    message_str += f"id: {id[i]}\n Имя: {Имя[i]}\n Фамилия: {Фамилия[i]}\n Отчество: {Отчество[i]}\n Телефон: {Телефон[i]}\n Марка: {Марка[i]}\n Модель: {Модель[i]}\n Проблема: {Проблема[i]}\nПробег: {Пробег[i]}\n Статус: {Статус[i]}\n\n"
    i += 1
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_str, reply_markup = markup)

bot.polling(none_stop= True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: 1) читать легче; 2) можно копировать; 3) поиск работает. Исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте "WHERE" как показано в документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html